# Angular 6 : How to setup routing app-routing navigate to sub project app-routing

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

Structure project :

```
my-app/
  src/
    app/
      app-routing.module.ts
      ...
  ...
  projects/          
    my-sub-app/   
      src/
        app/
          app-routing.module.ts
          ...
```

In app-routing.module.ts (my-app) :

```
...
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'my-sub-app',
  loadChildren: '{{ p a t h  o f my-sub-app }} app.module#AppModule'
}];
...
```

> ```
> Versions
> Node: 8.11.3
> NPM: 6.4.1
> Angular CLI: 6.1.2
> Windows 10
> ```

How to setup routing app-routing.module.ts (my-app) navigate to app-routing.module.ts (my-sub-app) in folder project ?

What to put {{ p a t h  o f my-sub-app }} ???

Comment: update your question with what you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you're looking for is `modules`, basically you create `ProjectModules` with it's own routing. To get that type of path like your folder structure you would need to configure it on your `tsconfig`, I recommend putting all these modules under a single folder called `Modules` just to keep your structure tidy.

Comment: Routing between two modules (modules have their own routes) or routing between two seperate angular projects??